# Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException laravel Error on the server

Tags: laravel, deployment, server, host

I am getting this error when I deploy my project:

> Declaration of Symfony\Component\Translation\TranslatorInterface::setLocale($locale) must be compatible with Symfony\Contracts\Translation\LocaleAwareInterface::setLocale(string $locale)

is there a way that I can solve it on the server without re-uploading?

Comment: delete cache and logs and check is the error occurs again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The server was running PHP 7.1 by default and that was causing the problem. Switched to 7.2 and problem solved.